# With upgrade to 4.7.17, I get "invalid price fields" warning

Tags: wordpress, price-sets

Since the upgrade to 4.7.17 (from 4.7.15) I get a popup warning about invalid price fields.  The fields are about memberships, but we don't use the membership component.  I would like to delete those fields, but I don't see any associated price set and there is no option to delete the fields.
At a minimum I would like to hide this warning but I don't see how to do that either.  Any suggestions?

```
Invalid Price Fields
the following Price Set Fields use disabled or invalid financial types and need to be fixed if they are to still be used.

Price Set   Price Set Field Action Link
Membership Amount   Membership Amount   View Price Set Fields
Member Signup and Renewal   Membership  View Price Set Fields
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the hacky way above works in 2023, there is one more possible solution without hacking the DB: please ensure related Membership/Event/Contribution Price Set exists. So if the lost price field is from a Membership Price Set, please create the set, even without fields - the error will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

Found a hacky solution.  In phpmyadmin, in the civicrm_price_set table, I changed the "is_reserved" field from 1 to 0.  At that point, the price field could be deleted in the UI, and all seems to be well.